# listing variable contents at certain breakpoint in windbg

Tags: debugging, windbg, breakpoints

I am trying to augment sort of a printf or cout at certain breakpoints. Is there a way I can tell windbg to put a breakpoint and instead of breaking just list variables when execution flows through that breakpoint.

I tried to find about this on Google, but everywhere I get help related to breaking on certain condition.

I am sure there has to be a way of doing what I am trying to do.

Thanks for any help.

-Shobhit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple command would be

```
bp MyFunction "dv;g"
```

Where `dv` displays the local variables and then `g` continue execution.